# how to get google openId using OAuth 2.0 in javascript?

Tags: google-oauth, google-openid, chrome-web-store, google-chrome-app

I'm writing an packaged app using javascript for google chrome web store and I need to identify the users e-mail. using Identity I've retrieved OAuth 2.0 token (by *chrome.identity.getAuthToken()* command). What next?

I've found [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login) but i'm afraid it can be used only for hosted chrome apps.

Answer (score 1):

The above documentation can be used also in cases where the application only has a client-side presence. You can extract the email_address from the id_token (https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login#obtainuserinfo); that would be most efficient. Or you can use the access_token to retrieve the same data from the user_info endpoint, which requires another AJAX request (https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login#obtaininguserprofileinformation).

If you manage to configure the G+ Sign-In widget for your extension you'll find out that it simplifies these tasks considerably. Note that G+ Sign-In has been recently updated and works for all Google account users (including Google Apps users) whether or not they have signed-up for the Google+ service. See https://developers.google.com/+/ for more information.

Comment: I can not make https request to get id_token.. How to do that?? For the second option I really don't understand where I should add the scope: "scope=openid%20email%20profile" and also how to send request..

Comment: To get id_token, you use response_type=id_token or if you want to get both id_token and access_token you can set response_type=id_token%20token

Comment: Both these parameters should be added to the authentication URL, that starts with https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth
The OAuth2Login documentation linked above will give you more information on how to put these URLs together.

Comment: tried that and got following error:
Refused to load the script 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=551985194472-ml6sl88rh7…030014731959905475378_1391896372328&q=select+*&format=json&_=1391896372329' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:". Note that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.